# Is it possible to modify advanced Microsoft Word options from a C# ribbon add-in?

Tags: c#, vsto, word-2010

Working in VSTO on a Ribbon Add-In for word 2010, language is C#. I am trying to make a custom bookmark editor (to be more user friendly). I want word to show bookmarks by default, the setting is in Options>Advanced>Show Document Content> Show BookMarks. Is it possible to enable this from the "outside"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option is under under Window.View.ShowBookmarks

I found it using the [macro recorder](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Show-the-Developer-tab-e1192344-5e56-4d45-931b-e5fd9bea2d45).